# Is it possible to set other attributes in a @property setter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

New to python, and wondering if you can you programmatically set class attributes in the setter of another property? For example: in the code below, I want to set the `days_off` property based on the value provided in the `years` setter.

```
class Employee:
  def __init__(self, years, days_off=20):
    print('initializing')
    self.years = years
    self.days_off = days_off

  def __str__(self):
    return f'employee with {self.years} years'

  @property
  def years(self):
    return self._years

  @years.setter
  def years(self, years):
    if  9 < years and years < 20:
      print('condition 1 hit')
      self.days_off = 25
    elif years > 20:
      print('condition 2 hit')
      self.days_off = 30
    self._years = years

test_employee = Employee(7)
other_test_employee = Employee(17)
yet_another = Employee(27)


print(test_employee.days_off) # 20
print(other_test_employee.days_off) # 20, should be 25
print(yet_another.days_off) # 20, should be 30
```

Comment: Yes you can. That's the sort of thing custom setters are for

Comment: The reason you're not getting what you expect is that you set `years` first, which sets `days_off` appropriately, but then you immediately overwrite that with the original value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Daniel Roseman mentioned in his comment, first you set the value of `days_off` when you set the value of `years`, and then you replace it with `20`, as it is the next assignment you do after `self.years = years`. In order to get the correct results, you need to assign a value to `days_off` before you assign a value to `years`. So, your constructor should be as follows:

```
def __init__(self, years, days_off=20):
    print('initializing')
    self.days_off = days_off
    self.years = years
```

Running it again, will return the correct results:

```
initializing
initializing
condition 1 hit
initializing
condition 2 hit
20
25
30
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the example!